# WordPress menu doesn't render after being selected in the Customizer

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been banging my head for a few days with a problem. I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a simple theme I'm working on that uses custom menus.

I'm registering the menus properly in functions.php:

```
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'primary' => __( 'Main Menu', 'themedomain' )
    )
);
```

and then displaying them in header.php:

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <?php
        wp_nav_menu(
            array(
                'theme_location' => 'primary',
                'depth'          => '1'
            )
        );
    ?>
</nav>
```

It was all working well until I used the navigation section in the customizer to select a new menu. After I did that it stopped working. The menus wouldn't show up. I checked the page source, they're not even being rendered in HTML.

I checked my menus, they're not blank. I even added new ones, still nothing.

I'm using WordPress 4.0.1.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

Here's the entire code I'm using for registering the menus:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wsy_setup' ) ) {
    function wsy_setup() {
        /**
         * Makes the theme available for translation.
         * Translation files can be added to the /languages/ directory.
         */
        $lang_dir = THEMEROOT . '/languages';
        load_theme_textdomain( 'wsy', $lang_dir );

        /**
         * Add support for post formats.
         * By default, all formats are supported.
         */
        add_theme_support( 'post-formats',
            array(
                'aside', 
                'gallery', 
                'link', 
                'image', 
                'quote', 
                'status', 
                'video', 
                'audio', 
                'chat'
            ) 
        );

        /**
         * Support for automatic feed links.
         * This will add RSS feed links to <head> for posts and comments.
         */
        add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

        // Add support for post thumbnails
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

        // Add support for WooCommerce
        add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );

        // Unhook the WooCommerce wrappers
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

        // Set the default thumbnail size
        // set_post_thumbnail_size( 200, 200, true );

        // Add additional image sizes
        // add_image_size( '<slug>', width, height );

        // The theme will use its own gallery styles
        add_filter( 'use_default_gallery_style', '__return_false' );

        // Prevent the loading of the WooCommerce default styling
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_false' );

        /**
         * By default, add a single menu location.
         * More menus can be added by creating another array item.
         */
        register_nav_menus( 
            array(
                'primary' => __( 'Main Menu', 'wsy' )
            ) 
        );
    }

    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wsy_setup' );
}
```

UPDATE: I figured it out eventually. I had a filter set that was meant to pull additional items into the menu. Only the function responsible for doing that was commented. It's all good now!

Comment: Does the menu work in other themes with menu support? Did you save your menu?

Comment: Can you post the complete code you use to register your menu (function, add_action). Also, if you're only using one menu try `register_nav_menu()` instead of `register_nav_menus()`

Comment: @IkoTikashi The menus work with other themes. Even when changing them from the customiser. I am adding settings to the customiser, so maybe that's why this is happening...

Comment: @IkoTikashi I've updated the question with the entire code.

Comment: I hade the same problem in my previous project when updated to wordpress 4.0.1 then after hit and trial i used this code ` wp_nav_menu(
            array(
                'theme_location' => 'Main Menu',
                'depth'          => '1'
            )
        );`
and it works for me

Comment: @ShahRukh I actually have that structure in a responsive menu container, but it still doesn't work... Thanks tho!